# ADF dynamically creating filename for a usql job

Tags: azure, dynamic, parameters, azure-data-factory, u-sql

Currently getting this error in a dataset that dynamically creates a filename to send back to a usql job.

Error - `"errorId":"E_CSC_USER_DATAPARTITIONEDOUTPUTNOTSUPPORTED","severity":"Error","component":"CSC","source":"USER","message":"Data partitioned output is not supported."`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a feature that is currently only available in a private preview. If you would like to use the private preview feature and give us some feedback on it, please send email to [usql] at microsoft dot com.

Comment: thank you for your response. For now I am going to create the dynamic file names in the usql dependency script of the pipeline. Will consider the private preview feature as well.